# NetBeans between Mac and PC

Tags: java, windows, macos, netbeans

I am creating Java projects using NetBeans. At school we run on Windows 7 and home I am using Mac OSX Snow Leopard. What will have to adjust as I develop back and forth between Mac and PC?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of checking in project configuration, especially since netbeans and eclipse have decent ant and maven integration.

If you create your project as a maven or ant project netbeans should be able to import the project regardless of your operating system and you should avoid any difficulties that may arise.  It'll also make it easy for you to share with other students (if you are working on a team) that may want to use eclipse or intellij.